# ROS2 Multiple Machines, Gateway + Hotspot + Ethernet (DOMAIN ID)

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, raspberry-pi, jetson, multiple-machines

I hope someone can help me with my problem. First of all, my setup:

PC: Connected to Raspberry Pi's hotspot (PC-IP: 192.168.12.19)

Raspberry Pi: Creates a Hotspot (192.168.12.1) and connected to Wifi (192.168.1.85) and connected to a Jetson Nano over **Ethernet** (192.168.123.161) also forwards Internet connection

Jetson Nano: Running ROS2 in a Docker. Works well. Topics are visible. (It is a Unitree Go1). IP of the Jetson: 192.168.123.14. Also has Internet connection shared by the Raspberry Pi

Now I want to see the topics on my PC. I tried to export the ROS DOMAIN ID. It does not work. I think I have a very special setup and don't know how to fix it.

What I have tried:

```
sudo ip route add <Jetson IP (192.168.123.14)> via <Raspberry Pi IP (192.168.12.1) dev <WIFI interface name>.
```

This allows me to ping the Jetson Nano from my PC, but still... no topics.